# Files of build folder in self-published package not consumed by third-party projects

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

Having a problem publishing a package with only build utilities. Being precise: I followed the [nuget guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) which files have to be where. So I created a simple [project][2] in which I just want deploy the `.props` and `.targets` files in the build folder for third-party projects. When I pack it with `dotnet pack Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.csproj --configuration Release)` the .nupkg file does contain all necessary files:

```
Listing archive: bin\Release\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.1.0.0.nupkg

--
Path = bin\Release\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.1.0.0.nupkg
Type = zip
Physical Size = 3027

   Date      Time    Attr         Size   Compressed  Name
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2020-01-11 18:13:12 .....          533          297  _rels\.rels
2020-01-11 18:13:12 .....          696          358  Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.nuspec
2020-01-11 17:03:22 .....          435          208  build\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.props
2020-01-11 11:28:08 .....         1188          532  build\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.targets
2020-01-11 18:13:12 .....          534          219  [Content_Types].xml
2020-01-11 18:13:12 .....          735          413  package\services\metadata\core-properties\3bab4543af344c95ae6210e86f61f55a.psmdcp
------------------- ----- ------------ ------------  ------------------------
2020-01-11 18:13:12               4121         2027  6 files
```

When I add this package (`nuget add bin/Release/Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.1.0.0.nupkg -Source "C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages"`) to my local feed, after I have deleted it of course, and let a sample project with customized feed sources include that specific package, the generated `obj/project.assets.json` will not contain the `.props` and `.targets` files it should:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "targets": {
    ".NETStandard,Version=v2.0": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/1.1.0": {
        ...
      },
      "NETStandard.Library/2.0.3": {
        ...
      },
      // ###############################################
      "Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage/1.0.0": {
        "type": "package"
        // Here should the .props and .targets files be referenced
      },
      "Test.Localization/1.0.0": {
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  "libraries": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms/1.1.0": {
      ...
    },
    "NETStandard.Library/2.0.3": {
      ...
    },
    // ###############################################
    "Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage/1.0.0": {
      "sha512": "vKfduDW8+hIYQ1s6zFO0EnCmJTSVGAzsvcDDM2YIEiIqksGX1WO/ERMvAkXmJR2Q0x92wFk+z0i448HuYmUWSQ==",
      "type": "package",
      "path": "teronis.packaging.projectbuildinpackage/1.0.0",
      "files": [
        ".nupkg.metadata",
        // Here are the .props and .targets files missing
        "teronis.packaging.projectbuildinpackage.1.0.0.nupkg.sha512",
        "teronis.packaging.projectbuildinpackage.nuspec"
      ]
    },
    "Test.Localization/1.0.0": {
      "type": "project",
      "path": "../../Teronis.DotNet/src/Packaging/ProjectBuildInPackage/test/Test.Localization/Test.Localization.csproj",
      "msbuildProject": "../../Teronis.DotNet/src/Packaging/ProjectBuildInPackage/test/Test.Localization/Test.Localization.csproj"
    }
  },
  "projectFileDependencyGroups": {
    ...
  },
  "packageFolders": {
    "C:\\Users\\<user>\\.nuget\\packages\\": {},
    "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder": {}
  },
  "project": {
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "restore": {
      "projectUniqueName": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\source\\repos\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test.csproj",
      "projectName": "Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test",
      "projectPath": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\source\\repos\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test.csproj",
      "packagesPath": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\.nuget\\packages\\",
      "outputPath": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\source\\repos\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\obj\\",
      "projectStyle": "PackageReference",
      "fallbackFolders": [
        "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
      ],
      "configFilePaths": [
        "C:\\Users\\<user>\\source\\repos\\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.Test\\NuGet.Config",
        "C:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Roaming\\NuGet\\NuGet.Config",
        "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NuGet\\Config\\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Offline.config"
      ],
      "originalTargetFrameworks": [
        "netstandard2.0"
      ],
      "sources": {
        "C:\\Users\\<user>\\.nuget\\packages": {},
        "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": {}
      },
      "frameworks": {
        "netstandard2.0": {
          "projectReferences": {
            "C:\\Users\\<user>\\source\\repos\\Teronis.DotNet\\src\\Packaging\\ProjectBuildInPackage\\test\\Test.Localization\\Test.Localization.csproj": {
              "projectPath": "C:\\Users\\<user>\\source\\repos\\Teronis.DotNet\\src\\Packaging\\ProjectBuildInPackage\\test\\Test.Localization\\Test.Localization.csproj"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "warningProperties": {
        "warnAsError": [
          "NU1605"
        ]
      }
    },
    "frameworks": {
      "netstandard2.0": {
        "dependencies": {
          "NETStandard.Library": {
            "suppressParent": "All",
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[2.0.3, )",
            "autoReferenced": true
          },
          "Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage": {
            "include": "Runtime, Build, Native, ContentFiles, Analyzers, BuildTransitive",
            "suppressParent": "All",
            "target": "Package",
            "version": "[1.0.0, )"
          }
        },
        "imports": [
          "net461",
          "net462",
          "net47",
          "net471",
          "net472",
          "net48"
        ],
        "assetTargetFallback": true,
        "warn": true,
        "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\3.1.100\\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The package in a sample project is referenced as

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage" Version="1.0.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

So it should include the build assets. I think it has something to do with the supported frameworks as this package should be supported for every framework/"framework" like `netcore`, `netcoreapp`, `net`, `netstandard`, and so on.

It should be said, that when creating the package the nuget analyzer does complain about

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage -> C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.dll
1>Successfully created package 'C:\Users\<user>\source\repos\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage\bin\Release\Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.1.0.0.nupkg'.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5): warning NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5): warning NU5128: - Add lib or ref assemblies for the netstandard2.0 target framework
1>Done building project "Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage.csproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Even when I know how to fix it by just creating `lib/netstandard2.0/_._` it does not solve my problem, that the `.props` and `.targets` files are not taken up by the nuget target that creates `obj/project.assets.json` intermediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little journey I found the solution. So there were two issues to solve.

First the source path: Do **not** use any nuget cache as feed source. Here for me (`nuget locals all -list`):

```
http-cache: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NuGet\v3-cache
global-packages: C:\Users\<user>\.nuget\packages\
temp: C:\cygwin64\tmp\NuGetScratch
plugins-cache: C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\NuGet\plugins-cache
```

The command `nuget add ..` does not fully "install" it, it won't unzip the assets (build, buildMultiTargeting, lib, ..) of .nupkg-file in its resprective folder (`<local-nuget-source-folder>/<package-id>/<package-version>/`). So the `.props` and `.targets` files will not be included by those projects who installed them. But when you specify another source location, add the package to it and then install it in a project, the package will be cached with its unzipped assets and the project will include them in `obj\project.assets.json`, yay.

The second issue belongs to the complain from the nuget analyzer. So, if I convert the .csproj to a .nuspec that would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>Teronis.Packaging.ProjectBuildInPackage</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>*not in use*</title>
    <authors>*not in use*</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <summary>*not in use*</summary>
    <description>*not in use*</description>
    <copyright>*not in use*</copyright>
    <tags>*not in use*</tags>
    <developmentDependency>true</developmentDependency>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="build\*" target="build" />
    <file src="buildMultiTargeting\*" target="buildMultiTargeting" />
  </files>
</package>
```

it **won't** complain about anything when packing it with `nuget pack`. Why is that so? When packing with `dotnet pack` (we use it because of .csproj file) it will also try to pack the symbols by default, but when the packing does erronous cancel, it won't tell you that, instead it annoys you with `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(198,5): error NU5017: Cannot create a package that has no dependencies nor content.`, but the .nupkg (not .snupkg) is already created. So you have to specify `<IncludeSymbols>false</IncludeSymbols>` to accomplimish a non-canceled build.

So for a fully only-build-files package, you would have a .csproj file like that:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>Allows project reference content to be added to the packing parent nuget package.</Description>

    <!-- We don't build a executable package. 
         We build an only-build-time package. -->
    <SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>true</SuppressDependenciesWhenPacking>
    <DevelopmentDependency>true</DevelopmentDependency>
    <IncludeBuildOutput>false</IncludeBuildOutput>
    <IncludeSymbols>false</IncludeSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="build\**" Pack="true" PackagePath="build\" />
    <None Include="buildMultiTargeting\**" Pack="true" PackagePath="buildMultiTargeting\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The `.props` and `.targets` files in `buildMultiTargeting` are just importing the `.props` and `.targets` files in `build\`.

Cheers.

Comment: Great work! I think you can now [accept it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) so that more members can see this useful info! See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), just a reminder :)